# elasticsearch and camel integration

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-camel

I am trying to integrate camel with elasticsearch.
In applicationContext.xml added the following

```
 <route id="timer-to-console">
        <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=10s"/>
        <transform>
           <simple>Hello Web Application, how are you?</simple>
        </transform>
        <to uri="stream:out"/>
        <to uri="elasticsearch://local"/>
    </route>
```

Then when I run

```
mvn jetty:run
```

I am getting the following

```
veryCounter=0, firedTime=Mon Apr 21 13:14:43 PDT 2014}
BodyType            String
Body                Hello Web Application, how are you?
]

 Stacktrace
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: operation is missing
at    org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer.process(ElasticsearchProducer.java:54)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
```

My elasticsearch is running locally, I am using ES 1.1.1.

what do I need to specify for

```
elasticsearch://clusterName[?options]
```

Thanks,

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. Again, I need to know, the format of that uri that I specified in the applicatoonContext.xml. I need to know the specific syntax. How do delimit indexName and operation? I tried "&" and ";" both didn't work. Here is exact line I have, suggestions?

Comment: <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="timer-to-console">
            <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=10s"/>
            <transform>
               <simple>Hello Web Application, how are you?</simple>
            </transform>
            <to uri="stream:out"/>
            <to uri="elasticsearch://local?operation=INDEX&indexName=sample&indexType=sample"/>            
        </route>
    </camelContext>

Answer (score 1):

From a quick glance at the [Apache Camel Elasticsearch Component](https://camel.apache.org/elasticsearch.html) page they show the following example:

> elasticsearch://local?operation=INDEX&indexName=twitter&indexType=tweet

This would INDEX (add) into an index named `twitter` with a type of `tweet`. You can use whatever values you want for the indexName and indexType.

*Update:* Looking at the Elasticsearch Camel Component documentation again... I think in order to use `local` as the server name in the elasticsearch connection, you would need to be running your local Elasticsearch instance with a clustername of local. By default Elasticsearch configuration (elasticsearch.yml) is setup to run with a clustername of `elasticsearch`

Comment: Also, I have tried 

    <to uri="elasticsearch://local?operation=INDEX&indexName=sample"/>
no luck either..

Comment: Looks like I need to know exact syntax for  <to uri="elasticsearch://local[?options]"

Comment: You need to specify both an `indexName` and an `indexType`. Try `<to uri=elasticsearch://localhost?operation=INDEX&indexName=sample&indexType=sample Also see updated answer.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. Again, the uri I specified in the applicatoonContext.xml I need that specific index, anyone tried that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the cluster name specified in `elasticsearch.yml`, i.e. if it says `cluster.name: elasticsearch123` then you have to route for example as follows:

`from("file:data_json?noop=true&moveFailed=data_json/.error")
  .convertBodyTo(byte[].class)
  .to("elasticsearch://elasticsearch123?operation=INDEX&indexName=myindexname&indexType=mytypename");`

Using `local` simply doesn't work for me. Unfortunately it doesn't even throw any error which makes it difficult to debug.

Also notice the conversion `.convertBodyTo(byte[].class)` - that's also essential, otherwise Camel converts the JSON files to the class `Properties` (it looks for a conversion from `GenericFile` to `Map` and it finds a fallback type converter to `Properties`). Of course, you could also convert to the other types supported by the component.

It's also worth mentioning that the camel-elasticsearch component of version `2.14.1` depends on `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:1.0.0` which is quite an old version given how fast Elasticsearch moves (the current version is `1.4.4`) and how often it likes to break compatibility. That said, the component seems to work with Elasticsearch `1.4.3`.

**Update**: the current master branch on GitHub has Elasticsearch upgraded to version `1.4.2`: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/2470023e25b8814279cbadb3ebc8002bed6d8fc8/parent/pom.xml#L144

The parameter/clusterName `local` in fact means that it will look for an Elasticsearch instance started in the same JVM, from Elasticsearch's JavaDoc ([NodeBuilder.local(boolean)](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/node/NodeBuilder.java#L138)):

> A local node is a node that uses a local (JVM level) discovery and
>   transport. Other (local) nodes started within the same JVM (actually, class-loader) will be
>   discovered and communicated with. Nodes outside of the JVM will not be discovered.