# Camel and Elasticsearch with shield plugin

Tags: java, elasticsearch, plugins, apache-camel, endpoint

How one can use Camel with Elasticsearch endpoint but with added shield plugin?

How to specify endpoint URI?

How to parametrize user and password?

[Documentation](http://camel.apache.org/elasticsearch.html) states nothing about, how to set user name and password.

There is long explanation about [Camel and Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205302/elasticsearch-and-camel-integration)  usage but there is nothing about shield plugin.

I am sure that Elasticsearch works with shield, as by using curl I can access DB setting proper username and password.

Comment: could you develop your question please ? Did you already try something ?

Comment: Sorry, but what shall I write, if there is nothing to show. 

And, yes, basic Elasticsearch "Hello World" works, but it has nothing to do with shield, as without user name and password I am getting like connection refuse error (like 401).

Comment: Its seems you added some linked and documentation, which is very useful and enought

Comment: As I cannot answer.
I made Camel code review.
It is a pitty, it seems Camel 2.17 has no support for the Shield plugin at all.

One can perhaps look at the file: *camel\components\camel-elasticsearch\src\main\java\org\apache\camel\component\elasticsearch\ElasticsearchConfiguration.java*

As it appears, to be able to work with Elasticsearch and Shield one shall write own endpoint.

This is documented at page: 
http://camel.apache.org/writing-components.html
http://camel.apache.org/creating-a-new-camel-component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication with Elasticsearch is supported from camel version 2.20. Please refer the below links.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11597[1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11597)

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-elasticsearch5/src/main/docs/elasticsearch5-component.adoc

Answer (score 0):

Just a short now. Camel till version 2.18 has no support for the Elasticsearch with shield plugin, so connections will not be established.

Perhaps it will come in the future, who knows :-).